# Large CSV Project

Tags: python, csv, math

so I am working on a project that reads, parses, and writes a MASSIVE csv file. The part I am focusing on right now is population of each region of earth. With each region there are three categories of population split into age. Population 1-15, Population 15-65, and Population 65+, I am writing this all in python and have come across some problems I cannot figure out. I will paste the code and explain further

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog 
import csv
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x600")
with open("REGION.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_reader :
        print(line ["REGION_ID"])
        print(line ["POPULATION_15"])
        print(line ["POPULATION_15_65"])
        print(line ["POPULATION_65"])


lbl1 = Label(root, text = "Enter orginal population (Estimate, Past figures only)").pack()
orpop = Entry(root).pack()


mainloop()
```

(code may be a little sloppy, it is my first project.)
Ok, now, they are about 2806 regions, and all have 3 categories of pop, now, the first thing i want to do is add all of the populations of all regions, so POPULATION_15 + POPULATION_15_65 + POPULATION_65
if someone can give me that code it would be appreciated.
Next I prompt the user to give a population in the past, a TOTAL of earth. then, the program will divide that population from the original one, then split it up evenly into three categories and all the regions. 
After all that it would export a new file of the new data.

Total pop divided by population less then orginal given by user, the ratio would be given of how much the populations of all three categories of each region would need to be reduced. like if you enter a population that was half of it was today, it would reduce all the populations by 50%. Whatever way works aslong as it gets the job done.

Comment: How massive is massive?! 2806 regions with a few dozen data points per region isn't that big.

Comment: the final printed line number is around 10,000

Comment: @tdelaney eventually I would like to add resources too, it would not be that hard, it would scale down the same way as population. But it has 30 or so "headliners" or whatever they are called.

Comment: Can you shorten your question and add a clear answer please? Thank you

Comment: @CodingNinja ok, well, there are 2086 regions, each with 3 titles, what i want to do is add all of the 3 specific titles then divide it by another certain number and export another CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the csv as you read it to only hold the data you want. As you go through the lines you can also calculate dependent data such as total regional population.

When you are done, you have a table where you can iterate rows or do calculations on `[row][col]` indicies.

```
region_table = []

with open("REGION.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        # filter interesting columns cast to proper data type
        converted = [row["REGION_ID"], int(row["POPULATION_15"]),
            int(row["POPULATION_15_65"]), int(row["POPULATION_65"])]
        # sum the various populations into a grand total
        converted.append(sum(converted[1:4]))
        region_table.append(converted)

total_population = sum(row[4] for row in region_table)
```

Comment: one more thing, it says  converted = [row["REGION_ID"], int(row["POPULATION_15"]),
NameError: name 'row' is not defined, what should i do about this?

Comment: Oh. I changed your "line" to "row" in the `for` loop.... for no particular reason except i find it tidy.

Comment: ok, also, what is the region_table line for? i am also getting a error for that.

Comment: Its an in-memory table of the filtered csv that you can then use for further calculations. You need to define it in your code like I did.